# Changing Text Correction Feature Programmatically

Tags: android

I want to enable "**Text correction**" feature of keyboard **programmatically**.
I can send user to the settings screen on "**Language and Input**".
But I want to **enable this feature programmatically** without going to that screen.
How can I do this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
Use this inside your EditText.

Comment: Thanks buddy, is it helpful ?

Comment: I appreciate your answer Patel Jaimin.

But my question is if "Show suggestions" feature is turned off from the settings of device then also will this work ?

I want to enable this feature of settings programatically.